# how to know that my pc is 100% clean?

Tags: virus, remote-desktop

I work as a programmer ,i want to make sure that no remote access tools RATS are on my pc before i work on my new project. it happened before that after finishing a hard project, a hacker went on my pc and stole my code and started black-mailing to give it back.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will never have 100% certainty. Store your sources on an external source (eg a USB stick or DVD), have a good virus scanner and firewall, and use an OS that has strong security - like FreeBSD.

Comment: What makes you believe you're compromised in the first place ?

Comment: If you're not sure if your _current PC_ is clean then you need to reformat it and reinstall the OS from scratch. Yes technically there could be something [infecting the BIOS](http://www.ehow.co.uk/how-does_4809843_removing-bios-virus.html), although this is unlikely. Also - just wondering if you're using source control? If you use a remote repository this will serve as a backup of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have said, firewall, and if you feel it necessary IDS/IPS too.  But to me, it's the wrong question.  You need to address these things:

### Forensics

Have you managed to work out how you were comprimised before?  If not, it would be a good place to start.  Knowing how your system ended up with a RAT on it in the first place means you can close off that door

### Firewall

As mentioned by a few others, firewall that stuff.  A box running two NICs and using   [UFW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncomplicated_Firewall) or [Iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) to filter traffic is a good start, although make sure that box is itself very locked down.  Consider whether you need to run each service on the firewall box too.  e.g. if it's in the same room as you, does it need SSH/telnet running, or can you just use it in person?

### IDS/IPS

If you consider it necessary, you could even add an Intrusion Protection/Detection System to the box.  There are [several freeware tools](https://www.alienvault.com/blogs/security-essentials/open-source-intrusion-detection-tools-a-quick-overview) to consider in this regard.

### System hardening

Both on the box you proxy through, and the box you develop on, consider some hardening.  Get a software firewall that is good for your OS, and antivirus for that OS too, and ideally some way to check regularly for Rootkits etc.

### Good practices

More important than any of the above is to adopt good practices.  It's no good setting up a hardware firewall if you then open ports whenever something doesn't work, and forget to address whether they need to stay open, and it's no good installing a rootkit finder if you never run it.

All of this said, base what you do on a risk assessment (useful to know how previous exploits worked for risk assessment, too), and don't go overboard.  You could spend a week building a nice little setup with custom hardware firewalls, IDS/IPS protection, hardware level AV, and all manner of other stuff, but if you'd do better with a simpler set up and spending that time working, consider whether that's a better idea.

### Audit

Try and find a decent security audit tool for your system.  If you are running linux, I find [tiger](http://www.nongnu.org/tiger/) is pretty good,

### Opportunism

The likelihood is that you weren't targeted.  Statistically speaking, people trying to make money out of security holes in a criminal way (like holding code to ransom) aren't seeking out particular individuals to exploit, but rather people who fit a certain demographic.  It's more likely that you were exploited last time because some script kiddie could find a dev server of some sort running or something like that, and was scanning for these particular things in order to perform the exploit on you that they did.  Your biggest aim is to make yourself hard to find and then target, as this is a much more likely scenario than a direct target of you and only you.  The other thing that makes me think this is that you were extorted for money, whereas a targetted attack would probably be trying to steal your code and keep it.

Consider whether you may have been targeted, but I think on the whole, closing any security holes you can find will be a good first step.  I think you can probably avoid this problem again with just the firewall, but a lot depends on how you were comprimised.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the malware/rat to connect to the C&C server, use a firewall.
You can setup comodo firewall to promt you each time an application is trying to reach the internet.

You will get promted many times, but you can use the remember me settings.

Also take a good look at the process and location of it, maybe use Process explorer to check the .DLL files that the application uses and see if there is something strange.

Besides that, you could also use malwarebytes anti-malware but if the rat/malware is encrypted it wont be any use.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

Purchase a cheap computer. Run your connections through it. This will serve as an inline machine to your connection. You could do a pcap dump on all outgoing, for further analysis. The idea here is to single out unknown ip addresses to put into a block list.

Comment: Consider installing an IDS such as [Snort](https://www.snort.org/) on that computer.

Answer (score 0):

There cannot be 100% security. Having said that you can take preventive measures to keep your machine secure.

There are number of ways to do this - 
1) Have a latest update of anti-virus software and scan your machine daily.
2) Turn on your Firewall.
3) Monitor your system logs.
4) Scan your machine with automated scanner such as Nessus.
5) Make sure you apply latest patch to your system and configure your machine policies according to industry standards.
6) Work offline and keep important data on a portable device.
7) https://resistsurveillance.org/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a Live CD, ideally with no hard-disk present on your machine (use an external (USB or network) storage to store your project data). As any other system it cannot prevent at 100% that nobody can access your system, however unlike any other system since the live CD is a physically read-only medium it will be really hard for any potential attacker to install any nasty software to maintain access to your machine across reboots. In case of doubt regarding a process or your workstation activity, a simple reboot will provide a reasonable assurance that your system if now 100% clean.

If this solution is not appropriate, or that you need to work on a system not available as live cd, you have also the possibility to apply the same principle using a virtual machine instead of a live cd: store you project data on an external storage, and in case of doubt restore the virtual machine to a previous state. However, be aware that some OS may react differently regarding USB storage and may launch executable malware from there.

Alternatively, you can also use an OS specifically targeting better security like [Qubes OS](https://qubes-os.org/), a Linux distribution which allows you to compartmentalize your activity easily. I relies on Xen virtualization, and would allow you for instance to separate:

- Your usual web navigation in an untrusted box,
- Your email in a semi-trusted box,
- You development work in trusted box with network activity disabled.

This way someone entering in your system using a web or email threat will have nearly no possibility to access your development data.